# Why do checkboxes in the gridview firstly after checking and afterwards unchecking in the PreRender stage eventually are checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me with following, just something weird is going on.
I have a gridview with paging where the first column is filled with checkboxes.

```
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataSourceID="..." DataKeyNames="EventID" EnableViewState="false"
                    GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" 
                    AllowPaging="True" Width="100%" 
                    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
                    onprerender="GridView1_PreRender">    

                    <HeaderStyle Wrap="false" />                                                                               
                <Columns>                    
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">                           
                       <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectAllEvs" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />                                
                       </HeaderTemplate>                                                  
                       <ItemTemplate>                          
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="EventSelector" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />                                  
                       </ItemTemplate>                                                           
                   </asp:TemplateField>                       
                       <asp:BoundField ... >
                        <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                       </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ... >                          
                       </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField ... >
                       </asp:BoundField>                         
                </Columns>                                   
    </asp:GridView>
```

CodeBehind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {           
        if (Session["PageIndex"] != null)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["PageIndex"]);
        }          
    } 
}    

protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // loading checkbox values from the session collection
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    LoadCheckboxState(gv);
    Session["PageIndex"] = gv.PageIndex;
}

 private void LoadCheckboxState(GridView gv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var chkBox = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("EventSelector") as CheckBox;
        int id = gv.PageIndex * gv.PageSize + i;
        if (SelectedIndexes.Contains(id))
        {
            chkBox.Checked = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            chkBox.Checked = false;
        }
    }    
}    

    private List<int> SelectedIndexes
    {
        get
        {
            if(Session["selectedRows"] == null)
            {
                Session["selectedRows"] = new List<int>();
            }
            return (List<int>)Session["selectedRows"];
        }
    }

private void SaveCheckboxState(GridView gv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var chkBox = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("EventSelector") as CheckBox;
        int id = gv.PageIndex * gv.PageSize + i;
        if (chkBox.Checked)
        {
            //see if we have an id added already
            if (!SelectedIndexes.Contains(id))
            {
                SelectedIndexes.Add(id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (SelectedIndexes.Contains(id))
            {
                SelectedIndexes.Remove(id);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    // saving current page checkbox values to the session collection
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    SaveCheckboxState(gv);

    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;      
}
```

When I first get to my page I check some checkboxes and then press F5. Apparently after pressing it I dont have any values in SelectediIndexes and all unselected checkboxes must be checked = false on the PreRender stage but they appear checked after all this. And the problem of the same nature: I checked some on the first page; went to the second page (currently having 2 indexes in the SelectedValues) and after pressing F5 the same I have checked the same checkboxes as on the first page, though they mustn't.  I'm absolutely confused with this. How can I fix this? Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason to that strange behavior. I'm using Firrefox. And one of the features of this browser is saving state of some fields when refreshing the page. If you want to refresh a page fully you should refresh it with pressed shift button. Tested in Google Chrome - works just fine.